# Scrape the information using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    options=options
)


def supplyvan_scraper():
    with chrome_driver as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        URL = 'https://zoekeenadvocaat.advocatenorde.nl/zoeken?q=&type=advocaten&limiet=10&sortering=afstand&filters%5Brechtsgebieden%5D=%5B%5D&filters%5Bspecialisatie%5D=0&filters%5Btoevoegingen%5D=0&locatie%5Badres%5D=Holland&locatie%5Bgeo%5D%5Blat%5D=52.132633&locatie%5Bgeo%5D%5Blng%5D=5.291266&locatie%5Bstraal%5D=56&locatie%5Bhash%5D=67eb2b8d0aab60ec69666532ff9527c9&weergave=lijst&pagina=1'
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)

        page_links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in
                      driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='h4 no-margin-bottom']//a")]

        # visit all the links
        for link in page_links:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.title h3').text
            except:
                pass
            
            
            details=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//section[@class='lawyer-info']")
            for detail in details:
                try:
                    email=detail.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row'][3]//div[@class='column small-9']").get_attribute('href')
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    website=detail.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row'][4]//div[@class='column small-9']").get_attribute('href')
                except:
                    pass
                print(title,email,website)
            # driver.back()
            time.sleep(2)

        time.sleep(2)
        driver.quit()


supplyvan_scraper()
```

I am trying to scrape email and website but they will give me `none` for `website` and `email`
the What suitable Xpath for email and website is there any fesiable kindly tell us  this is page link https://zoekeenadvocaat.advocatenorde.nl/advocaten/oosterwolde-fr/de-heer-mr-wr-kamminga/11253211600

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change xpath for email:

```
//div[@class='row'][3]//div[@class='column small-9']/a
```

and for website:

```
//div[@class='row'][4]//div[@class='column small-9']/a
```